# how to create record (host) in infoblox with ruby

Tags: rubygems, infoblox

Does anyone have experience with ruby infoblox gem? I am trying to create and delete records in Infoblox.

I can get next available ip from infoblox, but that's about it. Cannot figure out how to create and delete hosts.

Please advise, 
Thanks...

```
connection = Infoblox::Connection.new(username: 'myuser', password: 'mypasswd', host: 'infoblox(IP)', ssl_opts: {verify: false})

network = Infoblox::Network.find(connection, network: '192.168.0.0/24').first

ip = network.next_available_ip.inspect.
```

Answer (score 0):

require 'infoblox'

connection = Infoblox::Connection.new(username: 'username', password: 'passwd', host: 'infoblox ip', ssl_opts: {verify: false})

network = Infoblox::Network.find(connection, network: '192.168.0.1/24').first

ip = network.next_available_ip.inspect

puts ip.to_s.delete!('[]""')

host = Infoblox::Host.new(
      connection: connection,
      name: data[:hostname],
      ipv4addrs: [{ipv4addr: ip}])
host.post